# Django, MyPy: Incompatible types in assignment (UserManager)

Tags: django, mypy, usermanager

I have following errors when I am running mypy checking:

```
error: Cannot override class variable (previously declared on base class "User") with instance variable  [misc]
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "type[BuyerManager[Any]]", base class "User" defined the type as "UserManager[User]")  [assignment]
```

My code is following:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...


class Buyer(User):
    objects = BuyerManager()


class BuyerManager(UserManager):
    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status="buyer")
```

Can't find solution.
So, any help or advice welcomed)

The result of my research:
here found that the mypy issues error for this case because of it's not match to the Liskov substitution principle, so I did like recomended there:
objects = BuyerManager()    # type: ignore

Or maybe I should create a buyers filter method instead of overriding get_queryset and use it if necessary.

Anyway, if you have better solution please share, thanks!

Comment: Managers should be instantiated when assigned to the model class, e.g., `objects = BuyerManager()`.

Comment: Supra621: Yes, you are right and in comments bellow the code I wrote it instantiated. Unfortunately it doesn't help in my question((